# Why does Silverlight View not throw a null exception?

Tags: c#, silverlight

Given a Silverlight View with the following binding:

```
<TextBox Width="200" Text="{Binding Customer.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

and the code behind has the following:

```
CustomerClass Customer {get; set;}
```

This will not throw a `NullReferenceException` however the following

```
String FirstName 
{
    get { return Customer.FirstName; }
}
```

does when I attempt to bind to `FirstName` instead of `Customer.FirstName`, why is this and how could this be corrected? (Other than just binding directly to `Customer.FirstName` or initializing the `CustomerClass` object)

**EDIT**: To address the possible duplicate issue. I thought that the binding still tried to get a reference when the view is first initialized, is this not the case? If so then I can see the difference between getting a reference and just being bound at view time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that the binding still tried to get a reference when the view is first initialized, is this not the case?

The binding process is designed to handle null values and will check the initial target *reference* which is given and not attempt any action if null. *Remember binding is simply the process of reflection off of a named path/location* and not the actual extraction of the value.

When the binding discovers that the **location** it is trying to reflect off of which is `Customer.FirstName` is null, it stops right there.

But when it is given a binding of `FirstName`, that **location** *reference* for the binding is quite valid. Bingo! Then when the ultimate operation *after the binding* goes to extract a value the `getter` is called which ultimately throws an exception because either `Customer` or `FirstName` is null.

> how could this be corrected?

Look into adding to the binding with either [TargetNullValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue(v=vs.95).aspx), which is an alternate binding to use when null. Or directly providing a  [FallbackValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue(v=vs.95).aspx) to use while the binding is null.

Or design the GUI to not rely on sub properties of an object which may be null.

Comment: Awesome, answered my question fully and succinctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

XAML bindings will not throw a `NullReferenceException` in and of themselves, but they also don't catch exceptions that are thrown by property getters. In some "flavors," like WPF, there are extended binding properties like `FallbackValue` and `TargetNullValue`. (I'm not sure how much of that is supported in Silverlight.)

When a binding fails, a trace warning message will be written, but an exception will not be thrown.

In the first case, the property getter is evaluated and returning `null`.

In the second case, the property getter is evaluated but cannot return a value to the binding system because of the exception.

To correct it, simply check for `null` in the getter and return a default value if so:

```
string FirstName 
{
    get { return Customer == null ? string.Empty : Customer.FirstName; }
}
```

Comment: See my answer on Silverlight's use of `FallbackValue` and `TargetNull` value.